# 2010: How to display excel web access web-part page in an iframe?

Tags: 2010, iframe, page-viewer-web-part, excel-web-access-webpart

Is there any way to display page which contains excel web access web-part in an iframe window? I'm getting security error.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

This procedure describes the specific steps that you have to take to add an Excel Web Access Web Part to an existing Web Part page. To add a Web Part to a page, you must belong to the default  **Members** SharePoint group for the site. Note: This should cover your security required for the web access.

If no appropriate page exists, you might have to create a site page.

To add an Excel Web Access Web Part to a Web Part page, take these steps.

In the Quick Launch pane, click All Site Content. Then, on the All Site Content page, click Create.

On the Create page in the Pages and Sites list, click Web Part Page.

In the "Web Part" zone where you want to add the Excel Web Access Web Part, click Add a Web Part to display the Web Part Picker.
A Web Part page contains zone for adding Web Parts

In the Categories pane of the Web Part Picker, click Business Data. In the Web Parts pane, click Excel Web Access. Then, click Add.

The Web Part Picker shows the Excel Web Access Web Part

This adds the Web Part to the page and displays the Select a Workbook pane.

**Connect a workbook to a Web Part**

In the Excel Web Access Select a Workbook pane, click the link Click here to open the tool pane. The page changes to Edit mode, and displays the Excel Web Access tool pane.

The Excel Web Access Web Part displays a Select Workbook pane

Select and enter properties for the Excel Web Access Web Part in the tool pane. In the Workbook Display section in the Workbook text box, enter the URL or UNC of the workbook. If you do not know the URL, you can click the browse button, and then select the workbook that you want to use in the Select an Asset -- Web Page Dialog window.

In the Named Item box, type the name of a named item in the workbook (such as a defined name, the name of a chart, table, PivotTable, or PivotChart) that you want displayed in the web part.

In the Toolbar and Title Bar section and in the Navigation and Interactivity section, select one or more properties that you want to enable. If you want to disable a property, clear the associated check box.

To save changes and exit Web Part Edit mode, you can click OK at the bottom of the Web Part tool pane. Or, to stop editing and view the workbook in Display mode, click Stop Editing.

This displays the Web Part that you configured to use its associated workbook on the page.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-workbook-in-an-Excel-Web-Access-Web-Part-2c0925c1-f383-4179-88fe-febd1f912894)

Comment: I know how to display a workbook in a excel web-access web-part. My question was not that. I want to know how can I can display a page (which has excel web access web-part) in an iframe window. I was getting security error.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, as I was interpreting the issue as being able to display excel. From my understanding, you should be able to do this, using a page viewer webpart, which shows your excel web-access web part - instead of a standard iframe. Can you share the security error? It could be a few issues; one being cross-origin, if you have separate domains, In some scenarios, it could also be that you need to require <WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" /> on your page (via MasterPage) for your site. If you can share the error, I can provide more guidance, respectively. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I use a page viewer web-part. I'm added the screenshot in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are protections prohibiting the content from being displayed - preventing frame-able click jacking attacks. You an circumvent these, by including the following,

To resolve this error, you can add the AllowFraming control to your .aspx pages:

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />
```

Note:

This control instructs SharePoint not to send the X-Frame-Options header when this page is requested. Without the X-Frame-Options header, the page is able to be IFRAMED.

Alternatively, if you can't use this "tag" in your page, you can add the "meta" tag (to the page containing the content), respectively.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">
```

Source: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14221928/1539718)

Comment: Did this resolve your issue?